# Converting a Javascript map into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, javascript-objects

I am given a map of key value pairs which I have no control over, and I need to convert them into an array of objects, but in a certain way.

```
    let paramArray1 = [];
    let paramArray2 = [];

    paramArray1.push({username:"test"})
    paramArray1.push({password:"test"})
    paramArray1.push({contentType:"application/json"})



    let map = new Map();
    map.set("username","test");
    map.set("password","test");
    map.set("contentType","application/json");



    for (const [key,value] of map.entries()){
      paramArray2.push({key,value})
    }



    console.log(paramArray1);
    console.log(paramArray2);
```

If you run that code above, you will see two outputs. Both arrays have the same items in them, but what I need is for the second array to be in the same format as the first one.

How can I convert a map of KVPs into an array without it breaking them down into key: [key], value :[value] and instead just being {key:value} like in the first array?

If you run the code you will see the problem. Thanks in advance!

I have tried changing the comma to a colon to, but that results in using the WORD key, instead of the key itself. aka the ouput for the below code is : [{key:test, key:test, key:application/json}]

```
    for (const [key,value] of map.entries()){
      paramArray2.push({key:value})
    }
```

Comment: `paramArray2.push({[key]:value})`

Comment: Damn that was fast! Thanks so much!

Comment: I was working on some `Map` stuff earlier :p

Comment: another approach could be using the entry (key/value pair) directly: `for (const entry of map) paramArray2.push(Object.fromEntries([entry]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is `paramArray2.push({[key]: value})`

```js
let paramArray1 = [];
let paramArray2 = [];

paramArray1.push({
  username: "test"
})
paramArray1.push({
  password: "test"
})
paramArray1.push({
  contentType: "application/json"
})



let map = new Map();
map.set("username", "test");
map.set("password", "test");
map.set("contentType", "application/json");



for (const [key, value] of map.entries()) {
  paramArray2.push({[key]: value})
}



console.log(paramArray1);
console.log(paramArray2);
```